# How to print to stdout during unit test for c language

Tags: c, unit-testing, netbeans

I'm writing C unit test with this unit testing framework: [check](http://check.sourceforge.net/doc/check_html/)

It feels good, but now I would want to insert some test prints to stdout which would show in the results when I run the tests in netbeans.

Currently I only see messages that are inserted with the convenience test functions: [convenience test functions](http://check.sourceforge.net/doc/check_html/check_4.html#Convenience-Test-Functions).

How could I see in the outputs the printfs or some myself generated prints?

Example test code:

```
START_TEST(test_something)
{
    printf("a printf I would like to see in the output");
    fail("some fail message");
}
END_TEST
```

Now how could I see the printf in the code in the test output (or at least somewhere).

Comment: there are a few possibilities:  First a question: does 'fail()' output to stdout?  In any case, stdout is buffered, so it only actually displays under three conditions: 1) the end of the text string contains '\n' just before the closing "  2) the stdout buffer gets full 3) the program exits.   Note: it is possible to tell stdout to not buffer, but that is a major slowdown in program execution to do so.  Anyway, for the posted text strings, always end them with '\n'.   Well, there is a forth way.  calling: `fflush( stdout );`